# resigning first responder using interface builder

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I want to resign first responder of a UITextField object upon the user pressing done. Is there a way to do this using the interface builder alone? Or must I do it programmatically by using the delegate instance method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be done programatically, you'd do it like this

```
- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You'd assign the doneEditing method to your Done button.